# What could cause a serious social gender divide in a dystopian society?

Tags: society, near-future, gender

For details:

- Gender, not sex. As in the socially constructed binary, not genitals
- I need something that will create a divide to essentially drive the youth of a gender to want to secede from society (more than they do in reality already)
- Ideally it would be something which poses a serious threat; serious enough that people would consider it a priority over rebuilding society in a post-apocalyptic scenario

Any help is good help, I have a lot of scenario ideas but no viable cause for them to have developed.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I find your question both unclear and too broad.

Comment: Hi, @F Pisroria welcome to Worldbuilding! I worry that this could get closed as either too broad or too opinion based. You mentioned having a lot of scenario ideas, I reccomend maybe picking one and asking how that would develop.

Comment: A postapocallyptic society where gender can't stand each other. This is going to be a short story.

Comment: Wilfully driving the species into extinction? You might want to look into [Nihilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism)

Comment: @Rekesoft Per your observation, the "exile colony" may have trouble self-sustaining if there's only one biological sex in it... **unless**  it could be like the island of the lost boys, where you have a "standing wave" of population even though individuals come and go over time.  Honestly, dealing with that problem might be the most interesting part of the story!

Comment: OP I think @Lot-Of-Malarkey suggestion is the best path to getting question reopened.  You might consider also the deleterious effect on the main community if X% of their biological boys or girls just vanished like this...

Comment: I upvoted, as I think this is an interesting idea.  Do we need a flag, "brainstorming" for people searching for plausible ideas?

Comment: In terms of your use, would you consider LBGT to be 4 or 6 additional genders?  Agree with some others:  More details.  Bit too open ended right now.

Comment: In a post apocalyptic world ain't got time for seperate genders, seriously. Humans gene pool would be depleted enough that all generic diversity is needed. women giving birth and having children would become fat more important,  with at least 4 children pet women.  That is if society is to rebuild. ...  so while bakla might be okay,  tomboy would need to be having babies, and in post apocalyptic world only once way that will happen. ... also Trans won't be a thing as that surgery would probably be too dangerous, and once again it is removing genetic diversity from the genre pool.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest idea: Society blames that gender for the downfall of their civilization, doesn't matter if there's any truth to that or not.

Just take the scenario that in the wake of that apocalyptic scenario (religious) extremist leaders became the leading force in society since they promised stability and used that gender as scapegoats.

Religious background is the easiest, just make them proclaim the existence of that gender to be against god or something.